# Как заставить jQuery код срабатывать каждый раз для сайта без перезагрузки?

Tags: jquery, vue.js

Есть jQuery код,

```
function click() {
    $('.select_list_current').on('click', function(){
        // alert(1);
        $(this).parent('.select_list_wrapper').toggleClass('open');
        $(this).parent().find('.select_list').slideDown("slow");
    });

    $(document).on('click',function (event) {
        if ($(event.target).closest('.select_list_wrapper').length == 0 && $(event.target).attr('id') != 'select_list_current') {
            $('.select_list_wrapper.open').toggleClass('open');
            $(this).parent().find('.select_list').hide("slow");
        }
    });


    $('.select_list_radio').on('click', function(){
        var current = $(this).find('label span').text();
        $(this).parents('.select_list_wrapper').find('.select_list_current .select_list_current_item').text(current);
        $(this).parents('.select_list_wrapper').removeClass('open');
        $(this).parents('.select_list_wrapper').find('.select_list').css('display', 'block');
    });
}
```

который навешивает событие на следующую верстку

```
<div class="selected_relative">
                    <div class="select_list_wrapper ">
                        <div class="select_list_current">
                            <span class="label">Сортировать:</span>
                            <span class="select_list_current_item">По популярности</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="select_list">
                            <div class="select_list_radio"><input type="radio" id="by_popular" name="sort_list" checked><label for="by_popular"><span>По популярности</span> </label></div>
                            <div class="select_list_radio"><input type="radio" id="by_price" name="sort_list"><label for="by_price"><span>По цене</span> </label></div>
                            <div class="select_list_radio"><input type="radio" id="by_date" name="sort_list"><label for="by_date"><span>По новизне</span> </label></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Данные селекты встречаются на каждой страницы сайта.

Для того, чтобы функция `click ()` сработала я ее вызываю при загрузке страницы

```
$(window).load(function() {
 click();
});
```

И в своем компоненте

```
updated() {
            this.$nextTick(function () {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    click();
                }, 1000)
            })
        },
```

Но срабатывает это в 100% только когда я страницу перезагружаю. При обычном "гулянии" по маршрутам селекты срабатывают через раз.

Answer (score 0):

Я лично пользуюсь конструкцией вида:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.popup-link', function(e) {
        ... код ...
    });
});
```

Но так делать не очень хорошо.

Comment: что-то вроде делегирования?

Comment: @Jussia что-то типа того. Событие привязывается к документу, а он в свою очередь ищет нужный элемент и делегирует ему событие.

Comment: спасибо, я попробовала, но ничего не поменялось(((

Comment: @Jussia, добавил в свой ответ замыкание. Если не помогло, то лучше сформулируйте свой вопрос.

Comment: спасибо, но пришлось переделывать код с помощью vue. Только в этом случае стало работать